# Installing opencv on python 3.5.3 on raspbian OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

While installing `opencv` and `face_recognition`, it turns out the `face_recognition` library is not possible on python 2.7.13, but it is working fine on python python 3.5 where as `opencv` is working fine on python 2.7 but it is not installing on python 3.5.

I want to compile both on Python ! 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be possible, what gives you the idea it's not? Also, your question is really bad, because it doesn't pose a concrete problem but instead a vague call for help. Try posting actual problems you have when e.g. building opencv for python 3.5

Comment: My raspberry pi got hanged while I was installing sudo python setup.py install --compiler-flags "-mfpu=neon" .. i want to install face_recognition for python 2.7.11

Comment: It often doesn't work to compile these packages because the memory of the PI is too small. This then leads to crashes or other problems. I use cross compilation toolchains to solve this problem. It's a bit complicated in your case because you are compiling an extension through distutils, and AFAIK that doesn't support cross compilation. But you could try & do that by hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install opencv on Raspberry Pi Raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146273/install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian)

Answer (score 0):

follow the command: (it worked for me)

```html
-> sudo apt update

-> sudo apt upgrade

-> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python2 -V
Python 2.7.13

-> pip3 install numpy

-> pip3 install pillow

-> sudo apt-get install cmake

-> sudo apt-get install python-opencv

-> sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev

-> sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev -y

-> sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev -y

-> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev -y

-> sudo pip3 install opencv-python

-> sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libswscale-dev openexr libopenexr-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev



pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Depends on the system. for PI will take : 2 to 3 hr. (total time)

Thanks :)